# Observer onChanged never called

Tags: android, kotlin

**FooActivity.kt**:

```
class FooActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LifecycleRegistryOwner {
  override fun getLifecycle(): LifecycleRegistry {
    return LifecycleRegistry(this)
  }
  ..
  // <-- here mViewModel is null
  mViewModel.getBar().observe(this, Observer<List<String>> {
    override fun onChanged(bar: List<String>) {
      // Never triggered
    }
  })
  mViewModel.init()
  // <-- here mViewModel has changed
}
```

The `mViewModel` is confirmed to change. However the observer's `onChanged` is never called.

---

**Question**: why doesn't it work?

---

**Edit**: **FooViewModel.kt**:

```
class FooViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
  val baz: BazPagerAdapter? = null
  ..
  fun init(fm: FragmentManager) {
    mBar = listOf("1", "2", "3")
  }
  ..
  fun getBar(): List<String> = mBar
  ..
  fun setBaz(pager: ViewPager, periods: List<BazFragment>) {
    pager.adapter = BazPagerAdapter(mFragmentManager!!, periods)
  }
}
```

**Edit2**:

For got to mentiond, `getBar` already returns `LiveData`

```
fun getBar(): LiveData<List<String>> = mBar
```

And the `onChange` still wouldn't trigger.

**Edit3**:

```
class FooViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
  private var mBar: MutableLiveData<List<String>>? = null
  ..
  fun init(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) {
    ..
    if (mBar == null) {
      mBar = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
    }
    mBar?.value = periods
}
..
fun getBar(): LiveData<List<String>>? = mBar
```

Comment: can you post viewModel class code?

Comment: @chandil03 See **Edit** for details. Nothing fancy - `getBar` just returns a list of `Strings`. I have also `setBaz` method, that is used to set adapter (data-binding), added it in case it might affect something. Using `AndroidViewModel` so I can get a `Context`, also passing `FragmentManager` in the `init()`, so I can populate `BazPagerAdapter`.

Comment: This is not how it works, you need to return liveData class object from getBar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no observe method for type [List](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/).
The ViewModel has nothing to do with observing either, it is there mainly to have state that persists through configuration changes.

For observable data you want [(Mutable)LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData.html) objects. These are lifecycle aware and manage observers for their data.

Please see the code examples [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html):

```
public class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val mBar = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()

    fun getBar(): LiveData<List<String>> = mBar

    fun init() {
        mBar.setValue(listOf("1", "2", "3"))
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right about `LiveData`. I made a mistake in my example - it already returns `LiveData<List<String>>`. And the `onChange` still wouldn't called, that is why I am curious - what is the reason and how to debug this.

Comment: What does the actual init method look like? If you use `mBar = ...` like in the example, it will obviously reassign the variable and not change the value and call observers.

Comment: Hmm, I think the reason is here somewhere, since Android may not treat setting a `MutableList` value as a change for observer. I have tried to play with it without any luck - **Edit3**.

Comment: Your code still isn't correct. getBar returns a nullable type while in the activity you use it without as non-nullable. At the time you call getBar(), it would be null since it is initialised in init which is called later. If in the Activity you have some null checking (ie. '?'), it may be that the observer is never registered because bar is null.

Comment: I would advise taking a step back, and rethink the creation and registration of the livedata objects. Preferably, have them as vals so they always exist and accept observers. If you are still having trouble, please post the actual, or at least correct, code because some samples now don't compile.

Answer (score 3):

So the problem is when you call `init` method, it reassigns new instance of `LiveData` into `mBar`. And you have assigned observer to previous instance of `mBar` because you are calling `init` method after :

```
 mViewModel.getBar().observe(this, Observer<List<String>> {
    override fun onChanged(bar: List<String>) {
      // Never triggered
    }
  })
```

To solve the problem just initialise `mBar` with `MutableLiveData` and then change its value (**Do not re-assign `mBar` with another instance**).

Check following code:

```
class FooViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private var mBar: MutableLiveData<List<String>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun init(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) {

        mBar.value = periods // Changing value only, not new instance
    }

    fun getBar(): LiveData<List<String>> = mBar
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I have managed to find the answer.

If you are going to extend `AppCompatActivity` and you want to use `LiveData`, you will have to implement the `LifecycleRegistryOwner` interface and its only method - `getLifecycle`.

The problem was that:

```
override fun getLifecycle(): LifecycleRegistry {
  return LifecycleRegistry(this)
}
```

Had to be:

```
val mLifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this)
..
override fun getLifecycle(): LifecycleRegistry {
  return mLifecycleRegistry
}
```